# In views use the value of a field in next row, in current row

Tags: 7, views

I would like to use the value of a field in row 2 of a views table output, in row 1 so that I can do some basic math on it.

This is what I would like to do:

1. Title | Field_x | Field_y+Field_y(2) | Field_z
2. Title | Field_x | Field_y+Field_y(3) | Field_z
3. Title | Field_x | Field_y+Field_y(4) | Field_z
4. Title | Field_x | Field_y+Field_y(5) | Field_z
5. Title | Field_x | Field_y+Field_y(6) | Field_z
6. Title | Field_x | Field_y | Field_z
   etc.

I've looked at every views solution I could find and every module without any luck.

Any idea how I can achieve this would be amazing.

Comment: Have you had a look at https://www.drupal.org/project/views_simple_math_field already?

Comment: @leymannx Seems like that module is only available for D8.

Comment: @leymannx the problem is not the math, the problem is using the value from the next row. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I think you can store views result into an array (with [views_get_view_result](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view_result/7.x-3.x)) and then manipulate that array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this in a [hook_views_pre_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7.x-3.x) function.

I wrote a little code example that I think would solve your problem.

Basically it loops over the rows and sets the value based on the previous row's field and the current row's field.

```
function MY_MODULE_views_pre_render($view) {
  if (
    $view->name == 'YOURVIEW' &&
    $view->current_display == 'YOUR_DISPLAY'
  ) {
    // By default prev. row is the first one.
    $previous_row = $view->result[0];
    // Loop through all rows.
    foreach ($view->result as $row) {
      // Do some calculation based on the current and previous row.
      $row->YOUR_FIELD[...]['value'] = $row->YOUR_FIELD[...]['value'] - $previous_row->YOUR_FIELD[...]['value'];
      // Set the prev. row.
      $previous_row = $row;
    }
  }
}
```

`...` is probably `[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]` (I'm not sure), so you must debug the `$row` variable to see where the values are saved.

Comment: Hi @Jdrupal, yes saw your answer thank you. I'll have a look this evening to see if I can implement it my side and feedback.

Comment: Cool, I look forward to hear from you. Please ask if there is something you don't understand :)

Comment: @RickHarington Please review my answer and give feedback, thanks :)

Comment: I went the views php route instead, as it was simpler for me personally, but assuming that your answer works. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad that I could help you find a solution :)

Comment: @RickHarington Would you mind sharing your solution with Views PHP in D7? I have the exact same need, using the next row field value in the current one. Thanks.